# css zoom not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm **building an app using angular**. It is supposed to run on tablets and touch-enabled devices.

I want to give the user the ability to **zoom/scale up the app**, for those with bad eyesight and clumsy fingers. To do this I'm using this script, **which is executed when the user clicks a zoom-button**:
 Here is the code

```
<!--code start -->  
$scope.zoomLevel+= 0.1;

$('body').css({
   zoom: $scope.zoomLevel
});
```

This works perfectly in chrome, **but does nothing at all in IE11**.

**I'm using twitter bootstrap, angular and jquery**.

When testing it in **jsFiddle** I'm perfectly able to use **zoom in IE**, so I'm guessing that me, or some third party library is setting a property that affects the zoom property in IE.

- **What could this be?**

PS: I don't mind it not working in firefox. This app will always be run in IE11.

Comment: ["... it isn't recommended for production sites."](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/) You might want to try using the `transform` property instead, with the `scale()` function.

Comment: scale() does not behave in exactly the same way. It will not affect the layout of my app. I need it to behave like using the browsers zoom.

Furthermore, scale() does not work in IE11 either.

Comment: As i said, this app has a very specific hardware-target, so i don't mind cross-browser issues, as long as it works in IE11.

Comment: [It works fine in IE10, so I suspect it works in IE11 also.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/emzdWb)

Comment: It does not work in IE10. It does works in Chrome.

Comment: That CodePen is working fine for me in IE10. Did you click the link?

Comment: The CodePen works fine for me in IE10 and IE11.

Comment: The CodePen works for me as well in IE11, but as I said, the issue is that I'm suspecting that an IE-specific property has been set somewhere in my 3rd-party libraries or somewhere in my own css-stylesheets. I just don’t know what to look for.

Comment: @SimonBob Internet Explorer 11 *does* support scaled transformations. After you call `$.fn.css`, what does the DOM Explorer in the F12 Developer Tools show for the `<body>` element?

Answer (score 5):

The `zoom` property is an older feature that really shouldn't be leveraged today. It has poor cross-browser support, belongs to no formal standard, and as such I (an engineer on the IE team) would encourage you to find a more standards-compliant method for moving forward.

Since version 9, Internet Explorer has supported CSS Transforms, and the scale function. This particular feature has much better cross-browser support, and would adequately suffice for your needs. I've created a small fiddle that shows both zooming and scaling side-by-side, to confirm the similarity in the experience.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/hy5vup49/2/

After some discussion in the comments, you pointed out valid layout differences between `zoom` and transformational scaling. If you wish to achieve the effect of `zoom` cross-browser, I would instead encourage you to consider using `em` or `rem` units in your project, and leverage font-size inheritance as your zooming mechanism.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/024krs33/

Comment: the problem with transforms is the whole subpixel accuracy thing that may give you blurred fonts as a result, it is not an issue when using `zoom`

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should look into scaling instead. It seems that the implementation of zoom differs greatly depending on your browser. However I have these questions:
First, the following example should demonstrate that zoom and scale differs: http://jsfiddle.net/hy5vup49/5/ (only works in chrome). Zooming affects layout, while scaling does not. How would I recreate this behavior with transforms in a robust way?
Second, scaling does not work on MY page in IE. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: @SimonBob Zoom is not a standard, so implementation may indeed differ. That being said, if you're looking for something that behaves similar to zoom, I would suggest you adopt `em` or `rem` units as your project's standard, and use `font-size` inheritance to increase everything. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/hy5vup49/6/). With regards to *your* project; do you have a live link?

Comment: @SimonBob Does the second fiddle in the answer above help?