# CSS "zoom" behavior in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I want to apply a zoom factor to the entire body of a webpage via CSS (or JS if CSS-only is not possible). This would be easy in any modern browser, I can just use a CSS rule like:

```
body {zoom: 75%;}
```

This works correctly in Chrome, as you can see in these screenshots: the original page:

[image]

scales correctly in Chrome:

[image]

However, unfortunately I have to support IE 11 :/
And the same solution doesn't seem to work in IE 11: as you can see, applying a zoom factor to the page body doesn't scale the contents, it resizes the body element itself, making it smaller:

[image]

I tried compensating by changing the size of the body to something higher than 100%, but while this brings the body back to full size, it also disrupts the page layout (elements start overlapping/separating in weird ways)

**EDIT**: various comments suggest using scaling, but I already tried using

```
transform: scale(0.75);
```

but this doesn't give the result I want in either Chrome or IE. With `scale` I obtain a result similar to screenshot 3 in both browsers, the only difference being that in this case the body is centered with a white rectangle around it, instead of anchored to the top-left corner (which I assume is because I'm not using `transform-origin: top left`, if I also add that I obtain exactly the same result as in screenshot 3).

Is there any way to do this in IE? Ideally I would like to have the same behavior as if the user actually zoomed the browser window using `CTRL+` or `CTRL-` (which does work correctly in IE, and gives me the same result as in the 2nd screenshot)

**EDIT 2**: [sample page](https://sense-demo.qlik.com/sso/sense/app/d18a42f4-4cbb-4894-8f74-bbd0a431874a/sheet/4cf062bc-90ca-4d82-9120-113c0edf3fd1/state/analysis) where you can test this, just press F12 and try to apply a zoom < 100% to the body element. In chrome the entire page will scale, in IE the body will shrink instead (ps: on my PC this page makes the IE dev tools hang for a few seconds when you open them, but just wait a bit and they will start responding again)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css zoom not working in ie11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526798/css-zoom-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: @41726c: that questioned was answered with "use transform instead", but as I pointed out in my question that doesn't seem to work... I obtain the same result as in my screenshot number 3 if I user that.

Comment: Did you try to implement it with -x- vendor prefix: -webkit-? If not you can have try on IE 11. https://i.postimg.cc/tRtdXwJJ/108.png

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: I tried, but scale does not do what I want in neither Chrome nor IE. I updated the question with further info on the transform: scale approach.

Comment: It can be better if you post any sample code to produce the issue. so that we can test it and try to find any possible solution or workaround for it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: I edited the post with a link to a sample page where you can test this behavior

Comment: You can see the testing result with IE 11. https://i.postimg.cc/wvm9hPMm/43.gif On my side it looks like it is scaling the page while zooming in or out.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: thanks for your testing... but can you tell me HOW you're doing that? If you're doint that with the native browser zoom: I already know that works! But I need to do it with CSS. If you're doing that with CSS... please tell me what properties you're setting on what elements please :P

Comment: Yes, I was testing it with zoom option in IE. Looks like you are using code to zoom the page. Can you please share your code. we will again try to test the issue with your code to see the results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: it's in the second line of the question :) I'm setting the `zoom` CSS property on the `body` element of the page to `75%`

Comment: I mean that we cannot inject that css code in your test code. So it is better you add it in your code so that we can try to run it to check the output. Also I had find that this feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: you can set the rule very easily from the dev tools, just press F12, select the `body` node and add the rule from the "styles" tab (under "inline style"). Unfortunately I cannot change that test page, but with the dev tools you can easily obtain the same effect

Comment: I am able to produce the issue but did not get any solution or work around for the issue. I will search for any possible solution and if I get it than I will try to inform you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: thank you very much for your support, it's really appreciated. I know the zoom property is non standard, but it's the only one that does what I want... if you find an alternative I'll be happy to hear it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Master_T - any luck with zoom property to work in IE 11 ? or an alternative ?

Comment: @ReactDeveloper: unfortunately no, we ended up forcing users to move to Chrome.

Comment: @Master_T - Thanks for the reply :-)